# Tfs Can not Get Project Name from Query programmatically using @Project parameter

Tags: tfs

i'm looking for your help, guys! I want to get Current Project Name from query, using my custom plugin.

Here is my code

```
WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query("SELECT [System.TeamProject] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '@Project'");

foreach (WorkItem item in queryResults)
{
// SomeCode;
}
```

So result of Query is empty.. I have no idea why.. If i'm writing 
real Project Name instead of the '@Project' it's works.. Also i tried to write @Project wihout  quotes - also no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "@Project" in code like this.  @Project is only available within a VisualStudio work item query where it can infer the team project based on your currently selected project in the Team Explorer.

Comment: And maybe do you know how to get Current Project from TeamFoundationRequestContext ?

Comment: I don't think there is a "Current Project" in this context.  You are simply calling the API from C# code.  The @Project is available within Visual Studio work item query where you have a current project selected via the Team Project Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code if your plugin is an WorkItemChangedEventHandler:

```
WorkItemChangedEvent workItemChange = (WorkItemChangedEvent)notificationEventArgs;
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem wi = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workItemChange.CoreFields.IntegerFields[0].NewValue);

string p = wi.Project.Name
```